# ARKit or RealityKit – How can we detect a real world object to make an app like iphone default measurement app?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

i want to make an app exactly like iphone default measurement app in swiftui. I am succeeded in measuring the distance between one entity to another. But i want to detect a real world object what to do?

i don't know where to start please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.